# MessageBox не блокирует все окна

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk, Toplevel, Button

root = Tk()
but = Button(root, text="Press", command=lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Error"))
but.pack()

top = Toplevel()
root.mainloop()
```

Окно `root` при нажатии на кнопку `but` нельзя передвигать, а окно `top` можно, как сделать так, чтоб все окна были заблокированы.

---

Например:

```
edit_top.wait_visibility();
edit_top.grab_set();
edit_top.transient(root)
```

То все окна ожидают `root`, и ее дочерние окна тоже блокируются.

Comment: ну а сделать на крайняк свое ошибочное окна же можно

Comment: Можно, но как это оформить, чтобы было похоже на messagebox и звуки были такие же?